# How to hide the address bar on a mobile web such as chrome or android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-video

I'm trying to make videojs full screen on the android devices when the user enter the URL. 
However, the address bar is still there. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
}
```

This obviously has to be done on a load, see http://atlchris.com/1847/quick-tip-hide-mobile-web-browser-address-bar-improved/

Comment: I find this to be a nice way of doing it, hitting any browser that trick works for:

if( window.scrollY == 0 && window.scrollX == 0 )
 window.scrollTo(0,0);